# In Oracle Database 11g XE, how do I delete applications from the application builder from a deleted workspace?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, sql-delete, workspace

I just started learning SQL and Databases using Oracle Database 11g XE. I noticed that under the Application Builder section there is always a Sample Application, which application_ID is 100 for the first workspace. When I create a new workspace, the ID of this sample application in the new workspace increases accordingly, so for my second workspace it's 101, and so on. But if I delete a workspace, without first deleting it's application, the id for new applications still increases, which leads me to think that the application is still there somewhere even after I deleted the workspace and dropped the user... They don't show up anywhere, not even in the admin view... How can I find and delete these sample applications that no longer belong to any workspace? Thank you

Note: If I delete the sample application before deleting the workspace, then the next new workspace will have the same ID for the sample application, so that's why I believe these applications are still there somewhere undeleted when I don't delete the application before deleting the workspace.

Comment: Hi David, you are curious - that will take you far in programming! :) Try not to get too hung up on this, though. APEX applications are stored in many different tables in the APEX schema, but there's one parent table. For this reason, IDs are unique across the entire instance (all workspaces). APEX caches IDs at times to try to prevent collisions. For example, if we both start creating a new page in the same app and APEX only looked at the last page number created and added one, then one of us would have a problem at the end of the wizard. So it's not quite that simple.

Comment: Also, be aware that 18c XE has been out for a while now and, even better if you ask me, Oracle now has a free tier in their cloud which gives you two autonomous databases for free. This means you can focus on learning SQL without having to play DBA too (though that can be fun too). See this https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/ and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOn3HdoSs6s

Comment: Thank you very much Dan. I'll stick to 11g for now since it's what we are using in class, but I'll move to 18c when I feel confident enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, once you drop the workspace, all its applications (and everything else - shared components etc.) are dropped with it. The fact that Sample Application ID keeps increasing - in my opinion - depends on some *internal mechanism* which uses some kind of a "smart counter" / "sequence", i.e. if you delete an application it decreases, but - if you delete a workspace, it does not. Please, note that this is just my opinion, I don't know how it exactly works.

Anyway: to check applications you currently have, connect as a privileged user (such as SYS). First, check what Apex users you have:

```
SQL> select * From all_users where username like 'APEX%' order by username;

USERNAME                          USER_ID CREATED
------------------------------ ---------- --------
APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN_USER              156 01.06.17
APEX_LISTENER                         173 05.03.19
APEX_PUBLIC_USER                       86 10.10.16
APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER                 174 05.03.19
APEX_050000                            87 10.10.16
APEX_050100                           154 01.06.17
APEX_180200                           178 08.03.19

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Then find applications within certain Apex user; as you're on 11g XE and if you didn't upgrade Apex, I believe you have `APEX_040000` (which is built-in into 11g XE). I don't have it, but I do have other versions, so:

```
SQL> select workspace, application_id, application_name, owner
  2  from apex_050100.apex_applications
  3  order by application_id;

WORKSPACE       APPLICATION_ID APPLICATION_NAME               OWNER
--------------- -------------- ------------------------------ ---------------
RNAL                       100 Sample Database Application    RNAL
WEB                        101 Sample Database Application    WEB
RNAL                       129 Warehouse                      RNAL
MBUN                       130 web_service                    MBUN
ORAGIS                     131 GIS                            ORAGIS
<snip>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and the apps from deleted workspaces don't show up, so I guess you're somehow right when you say there's some kind of internal counter. I'll try not to think much about that if my OCD let's me, thank you again.